# How to select only text of h2 tag ignoring the other html tags

Tags: jquery, html

I has as

tag For example

### Anirban bhattacharjee5

.I want only the text of h2 tag like Anirban Bhattacharjee through jquery.I give  a try but it returns Anirban Bhattacharjee5.

```
<div class="client_details">
<h2>anirban bhattacharjee<span class="client_rating">5</span></h2>
```

Mycode

```
var name=$(".client_details h2").text()
```

Comment: Can we see the html codes?

Comment: <div class="client_details">
<h2>anirban bhattacharjee<span class="client_rating">5</span></h2>

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the textnode of h2 and ignore the rest using:

```
$('.client_details h2').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
}).text();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ujuxLedm/)**

Answer (score 0):

`.contents()` is the method you are looking for. You can use it like below:

```js
var h2 = $("h2").contents()[0];

console.log(h2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>anirban bhattacharjee<span class="client_rating">5</span></h2>
```

so you can use:

```
var h2 = $(".client_details h2").contents()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(".client_details").find("h2").contents()[0]
```

The above line will return you *"anirban bhattacharjee"*